# Restrict SVG elements drag within the SVG container

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

Few SVG elements are dynamically created inside an SVG container which can be dragged freely. 
How to restrict the drag only within the height and width of the container?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9J25r/59/)

Script:

```
addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown, false);
var mx, my;
var dx, dy;
var mainsvg = document.getElementById('svg');
var selectedElement;
var eleTx, eleTy;

function getSvgCordinates(event) {

    var m = mainsvg.getScreenCTM();
    var p = mainsvg.createSVGPoint();

    var x, y;

    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;

    p.x = x;
    p.y = y;
    p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;

    x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
    y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

    return {x: x, y: y};
}

function mousedown(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'arrow_t') {
        panning('up');
    }
    else if (event.target.id === 'arrow_b') {
        panning('down');
    }
    else  if (event.target.id.split('_')[0] === 'rect') {

        selectedElement = event.target;
        var translatexy = selectedElement.getAttribute('transform');
        translatexy = translatexy.split('(');
        translatexy = translatexy[1].split(',');

        eleTx = translatexy[0];
        translatexy = translatexy[1].split(')');
        eleTy = translatexy[0];

        eleTx = parseFloat(eleTx);
        eleTy = parseFloat(eleTy);

        var xy = getSvgCordinates(event);

        mx = xy.x;
        my = xy.y;

        mx = parseFloat(mx);
        my = parseFloat(my);

        addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
        addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);
    }
}

function drag(event) {
    var xy = getSvgCordinates(event);
    dx = xy.x - mx;
    dy = xy.y - my;

    selectedElement.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + (eleTx + dx) + ',' + (eleTy + dy) + ')');
}
function mouseup(event) {

    removeEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
    removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup, false);
}
```

SVG Html:

```
 <div style="position: relative;top: 50px;left: 20px; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color:  bisque">
    <svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="300" width="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
      <rect id="rect_1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red" transform="translate(25,50)"/>
      <rect id="rect_2" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="20" fill="blue" transform="translate(225,150)" />
      <rect id="rect_3" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" fill="green" transform="translate(75,200)" />
   </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean here. Do you mean stop the elements being dragged outside the SVG? Is partially outside okay? Or do they have to be fully inside?  You have code to pan the viewBox. Do they have to be restricted to the current viewBox? Or the SVG? Or do you mean stop the mouse pointer going outside the SVG container?  Why are you not just comparing the drag coordinates to the SVG width and height and clamping them to that range if they go outside?

Comment: Need to stop the elements being dragged outside the container. Partially outside is NOT okay. Have to be fully inside. Restrict them at the boundary of the container(I guess, the container). When dragging, mouse pointer needs to stop , else it can go out of container. Can you script the comparing of drag coordinates to width and height and how to clamp it?

Comment: There is no way to constrain the mouse pointer within an area of the page. The browser does not have any method to do that. You will only be able to stop the dragged item at the boundary. The mouse pointer will continue to move.

Comment: It's fine if the pointer continues to move. Main issue is not to let the svg element outside the area.

Comment: When you start dragging an element. Get the bounds of the element (you can call `getBBox()` on the element for that). Then use those values to check the mouse position as you drag.  If the position is illegal, don't adjust the transform.

Comment: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/